# Make div text change on click based on PHP data using Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Let's say I have in a PHP file a div called `myDiv`, an image called `myImg`, and a PHP variable called `$x`. 
When someone clicks on `myImg`, I need `myDiv's` text to change based on the value of `$x`.

For example, let's say I want `myDiv's` text to change to `"Hello"` if `$x==1`, and to `"Bye"` if `$x==2`.

Everytime the text changes, the value of `$x` will change too, in this case, let's say if `$x==1` when `myImg` is clicked, then `$x's` value will become `2`($x=2), and viceversa.

I'm using `jQuery`, but I read that I need to use `Ajax` too for this (To check on the server the value of `$x`), but I can't figure out how to do it. I read about `Ajax`, but none of the examples explains something like this.

Comment: If you don't know where to start, but know how to do this purely in javascript (since you're just incrementing a value), then do it that way and post the code. Some relatively straight-forward changes to the event will suffice to convert it to Ajax.

Comment: I posted revised solution as a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add the revised solution in a new answer so you can still see the earlier examples as the code may provide useful examples.

In this example, we use a session variable to store the value between ajax calls.

FILE1.php

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#myImg').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "FILE2.php",
                data: '',
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="myDiv">
    Click picture below to GO:<br />
    <img id="myImg" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/783e6dfea0dcf458037183bdb333918d?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
</div>
```

---

FILE2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['myNum'])) {
    $x = $_SESSION['myNum'];
}else{
    //No session set yet, so initialize with x = 1
    $x = 1;
}

if ($x == 1) {
    $_SESSION['myNum'] = 2;
    echo 'Hello its a one';
}else{
    $_SESSION['myNum'] = 1;
    echo 'Goodbye TWO';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ajax, but you could use it. If you use AJAX, then you'll need a second php file that simply echoes back the Hello or Bye.

This first example gives the result you want without ajax. Just save this into a PHP file and browse to that page:

```
<?php
    $x = 2;
?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#myImg').click(function() {
            if (<?php echo $x;?> == 1) {
                alert ('Hello, its a one');
            }else{
                alert('Goodbye TWO');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="myDiv">
    Click on the image below:<br />
    <img id="myImg" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/783e6dfea0dcf458037183bdb333918d?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
</div>
```

---

To do the same thing using AJAX, change it to be like this:

First file: FILE1.php

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#myImg').click(function() {
            var theNumber = $('#myInput').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "FILE2.php",
                data: 'myNumber=' + theNumber,
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="myDiv">
    Enter number to send to FILE2:
    <input type="text" id="myInput"><br />
    <br />
    Click picture below to GO:<br />
    <img id="myImg" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/783e6dfea0dcf458037183bdb333918d?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
</div>
```

---

and FILE2.php

```
$x = $_POST['myNumber'];

if ($x == 1) {
    echo 'Hello its a one';
}else{
    echo 'Goodbye TWO';
}
```

Comment: Your code makes the evaluation part, but it does not change the value of the variable, remember the value has to change with every click, and the change has to be on the server.

Comment: Alright, let me work on that. I'll post a response in a few mins.

Comment: See new answer -- I thought it best to leave this one as it was for future reference, rather than deleting the existing code. You might find the `$_POST[]` assignments to be useful someday.