# Providing updating suggestions list with javascript, php and ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to modify [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) on making a live updating list to integrate it with my API. So, instead of using GET on the page with the form, I'd like to send it to that page via a function call.

Ok, So the problem is that it's not returning anything. I'm not sure if gethint.php is actually receiving a value. If you look at gethint.php on the link I provided, it sets

```
$q = $_GET['q'].
```

When I echo that nothing shows, so I don't think it's sending the value, despite the alert message showing what's in the box (on message.php)

So, here's my form

```
// message.php

//function to display the hint sent from gethint.php
function message_hint($hint){
    echo $hint;
}

//displays the form for sending messages
function send_message_form($to_user,$title,$message){
    include 'gethint.php';
    ?>
    <table>
    <form name = "send_message" method="post">
    <td>Send A Message</td>
    <tr><td>To:</td><td><input type = "text" size="50" name="to_user" id = "to_user" value ="<? echo $to_user; ?>" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type = "text" size="50" name="message_title"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Message:</td><td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message_details"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit_message"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <?
}
```

Here's the head of message.php

```
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str){
var to_user = document.getElementById("to_user").value //to_user is the id of the textbox
if (str.length==0){  
    to_user.innerHTML="";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            alert(to_user) //properly displays the name via alert box
        to_user.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+to_user,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
```

The page gethint.php is exactly the same, aside from this at the bottom.

```
//echo $response //this was the original output
$message = new messages;
$message->message_hint($response);
```

Comment: ......and what's your question? What have you tried? Do you get any error messages? If so, what are those?

Comment: Nothing appears. It doesn't return anything. I'm not sure if the page is actually receiving a value. If you look at gethint.php on the link I provided, it sets $q = $_GET['q']. When I echo that nothing shows, so I don't think it's sending the value, despite the alert message showing what's in the box (on message.php)

Comment: You can check what gethint.php echo in navigator debugging tool, as you request the file as a xmlhttprequest, it won't show anything. You can alert xmlhttp.responseText in your onreadystatechange function too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, I recommend using jQuery for AJAX calls. See [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499559/make-div-text-change-on-click-based-on-php-data-using-ajax/13501242#13501242).

Next, I suggest using jQueryUI for your autocomplete functionality. See [the example on this page](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Your code will be reduced by > 50% and you may find it much easier to understand.

Comment: Awesome, I used the jquery auto complete functionality and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know how it worked out for you. We all have a lot to thank John Resig for.