# getelementbyid with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I send to a php page a request and the output is like that

```
   <?php
   echo "<div id=\"someid\">
         innerHTML
        </div>"
   ?>
```

I try to catch the element but it doesnt work

```
     var a=document.getElementById('someid');
     alert(a.innerHTML);//alert nothing
```

How do I fix it with pure javascript?

Comment: When is the JavaScript being executed? Make sure it's run _after_ you actually define the node.

Comment: How are you making the Ajax call? When are you executing `getElementById`? Please provide more information. The solution is to execute the code at the right moment, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the content of a PHP page with AJAX (not `include`ing it), you have to append it to the DOM somewhere.

Are you appending it to the DOM in your code?

---

If you are using `include`, `require`, etc. then that is not AJAX.

You would have to wait until the page is loaded, so the code would go something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('foo');
    alert(elem.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code into a proper ajax structure. It should look like [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499559/make-div-text-change-on-click-based-on-php-data-using-ajax/13501242#13501242).